# Problem with indentation and alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation

I am writing my thesis in `book` document class. The command `\indent` is not working. Also, the lines are not aligned on the right side. What could be the problem?

Comment: Please, show us the problem with a minimal code or screenshot. May you'd like to use `\usepackage{indentfirst}`

Comment: I am new to this site, how to share a code or screenshot? Userpackage "indent first" creates indentation only at the starting of every paragraph...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: For that, I need to have at least 5 reputation

Comment: @user92156, now you have 6.

Comment: @sigur: can you give me your email id? I can send you the code...

Comment: Can not you edit your post?

Comment: @user92156 you can edit your question to add a small complete document that shows the problem, and use the `{}` button to format the code section.

Comment: As a test, put    \setlength{\parindent}{.5in} in front of the    \indent.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a previous `\raggedright` is still active.

Example:

```
\begin{document}
\subsection*{Indenting and justification}
\lipsum[2-3]

\subsection*{Ragged right without indenting}
\raggedright
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- The amount of indenting at the start of a paragraph is controlled by the register `\parindent`. It can be changed, e.g. by

  ```
  \setlength{\parindent}{2em}% default 20pt
  ```
- The first paragraph after a section (chapter, ...) title is not indented by default, see the example above. If needed, it can be changed by package `indentfirst`.
- `\raggedright`, `\raggedleft`, `\centering` and their environment forms `flushleft`, `flushright`, and `center` set the `\parindent` to zero.
- The command forms `\raggedright`, `\raggedleft`, and `\centering` remain active until the current group is closed. Caution: TeX uses the settings that are active at the *end* of a paragraph. An empty line or `\par` ends a paragraph.
- Environment `minipage` sets `\parindent` to zero.

Comment: I would add that, in general, using `\indent` or `\noindent` in a document might be a sign of bad use, or bad habit.